# How to give permission to files in android using cordova

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, vue.js

I have created a vue project where I am using cordova as plugin in vue. I have a scenario where using cordova file-transfer plugin I want to upload the file on to the server I have created in node.js using multer package.

I can able to select the files but the files aren't getting upload because of some permission denial.
So how can I resolve my problem I have added the permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml` file but still its denying my permission I don't what the hell is wrong with this application.

Any help would be appreciated...

**CLIENT SIDE CODE**

```js
<template>
    <div><br>
        <hr><br><br>
        <v-btn color="warning" @click="selectFiles()">Upload Files</v-btn>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return { 
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady , false);
        function onDeviceReady() {
            console.log(window.FileTransfer);
        }
    },
    methods: {
        selectFiles() {
            window.fileChooser.open((file) => {
                this.upload(file.uri + file.name)
            })
        },
        upload(fileURL){
            var permissions = window.cordova.plugins.permissions;
            permissions.hasPermission(permissions.CAMERA, function( status ){
            if ( status.hasPermission ) {
                alert("Yes :D ");
            }
            else {
                alert("No :( ");
                 permissions.requestPermissions(
                    [permissions.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT],
                    function(status) {
                        if( !status.hasPermission ) alert("hhh");
                    },
                   alert('Camera or Accounts permission is not turned on'));
            }
            });

            var path = fileURL
            path = path.replace("%", "%25");
            alert('path: '+path)
            fileURL = path
            var options = new window.FileUploadOptions();
            options.fileKey = "image";
            options.httpMethod = 'POST';
            options.fileName = fileURL.substr(fileURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
            var ft = new window.FileTransfer();
            ft.upload(fileURL, encodeURI("http://localhost:8000/user/fileUpload"), (r)=>
            { 
                console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
                console.log("Response = " + r.response);
                console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);}, (error)=>{
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
                console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
                }, options);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**SERVER SIDE CODE**

```js
var express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 8000;
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('hello people');
});

var multer = require('multer');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, '/upload');
     },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null , file.originalname);
    }
});



var upload = multer({dest:'uploads/'});
// var upload = multer({ storage: storage })




app.post('/user/fileUpload', upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
    try {
      res.send(req.file);
    }catch(err) {
      res.send(400);
    }
  });

  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('listening to the port: ' + port);
});
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```js
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10000" android:versionName="1.0.0" package="com.vue.example.app" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="org.apache.cordova.camera.FileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/camera_provider_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

When I am selecting the image file from the folder its giving me the alert message of **Camera or Accounts permission is not turned on** and then its giving the alert message of something like this:-

`{"code";3,"source"."content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%253A1961Image-name.jpg","target":my server api. "Permission Denial":reading com.android.providers.media.documents/MediaDocumentsProvideruri requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related API's.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it the only thing I was doing wrong is that I was passing the name of file with its uri, we only need to pass the uri in **fileChooser.open()** function. I will post the client side code. Here is the solution :-

**SOLVED CLIENT CODE**

```js
<template>
    <div><br>
        <hr><br><br>
        <v-btn color="warning" @click="selectFiles()">Upload Files</v-btn>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady , false);
        function onDeviceReady() {
            console.log(window.FileTransfer);
        }
    },
    methods: {
        selectFiles() {
            window.fileChooser.open((file) => {
                this.upload(file.uri);
            })
        },
        upload(fileURL) {
            var options = new window.FileUploadOptions();
            options.fileKey = "image";
            options.httpMethod = 'POST';
            options.fileName = fileURL.substr(fileURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
            var ft = new window.FileTransfer();
            ft.upload(fileURL, encodeURI("http://192.168.1.111:8000/user/fileUpload"), (r)=>
            { 
                alert("uploaded successfully..")
                console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
                console.log("Response = " + r.response);
                console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);}, (error)=>{
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
                console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
            }, options);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```